# Get py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class when use PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I ran this code and have an error.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.\
    config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://repos.spark-packages.org/").\
    config("spark.jars.packages", "saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.11,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0").\
    enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    
    df_spark_temp = spark.read.format('com.github.saurfang.sas.spark').load('18-83510-I94-Data-2016/i94_apr16_sub.sas7bdat')
    df_spark_temp.limit(5).toPandas().show()
```

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.SasRelation.<init>(SasRelation.scala:48)
        at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.SasRelation$.apply(SasRelation.scala:42)
        at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
        at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:39)
        at com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:185)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 23 more
```

Python version: 3.9.6
JAVA version: 17.0.4.1
Pyspark version: 3.3

I searched for same issues in stack overflow, and most of them said it is may because the scala version.
I haven't installed scala before, do I need to install scala or I can change the setting in JAVA?

And I type PySpark --version and it shows

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.0
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.15, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.4.1
```

Does it mean I need to install scala version 2.12.15 or I already have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All libraries must be compiled for the same Scala version you are running with.

I'm not familiar with PySpark but I see that at least `spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.11` seems to be compiled for Scala 2.11 given its version number.

If you're running with Scala 2.12, look for using `spark-sas7bdat:3.0.0-s_2.12` instead.

*Personal note: this library seems to not be maintained at all, consider using another one if that's for production code.*

Comment: Thanks Gael! It works when using `spark-sas7bdat:3.0.0-s_2.12`.
The library you mean `https://repos.spark-packages.org/` this repo? I only do this for studying, but I will take a note. Thanks again.

Comment: I mean the library https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat.